# Omit Swift from Objective-C header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have created an extension to `DispatchQueue` in Xcode 8 / Swift 3, and as I also have Objective-C code which coexists with swift the extension is included in the Objective-C header as `@interface OS_dispatch_queue`. This causes an error as `OS_dispatch_queue` is a protocol not class. Until this bug is fixed, is there any way I can exclude the extension from the Objective-C header?

[Example project](http://www.filedropper.com/test_5)

Comment: I can't reproduce. If I write `extension DispatchQueue { func hello() { } }`, it doesn't show up in my `Project-swift.h`. Can you edit your question to include an example we can try?

Comment: @robmayoff I've done that.